# Cordova - read/write access to shared folder in Win10

Tags: cordova, uwp, cordova-win10

At work we have an existing Cordova app that runs on Android. When importing/exporting data, we implement the following process:

- Data is exported from our desktop app into a sqlite database
- The sqlite database is copied from the host PC to the Android device (using the `sdcard`)
- The Cordova app is taken offline/onsite and is used to update the sqlite database
- When the user has finished with the Cordova app (and returns to base) the sqlite file is copied back to the host
- The desktop app is used to import updated data from the sqlite database

I'm currently porting the Cordova app to Windows UWP (specifically, Windows 10). Is there a way to achieve the above using the file system? Originally, I thought that it would be possible to copy the files to a folder underneath "Documents" and the app would be allowed to read/write this content.

However, when I inspect the object returned by `window.requestFileSystem` - it has 2 properties `root` and `winpath`. It looks like I only have read/write access to the app folder/sandbox.

Can this be done, or do I have to start looking at network-based options? Our clients prefer a file-based solution. Moving to a network-based solution for them will be undesirable.

Is there a way to upload/download files to a shared location on the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to upload/download files to a shared location on the device?

Yes, there is a way to upload/download files to a shared location on the device, but not with `File Plugin`. For the directories that file plugin can access, please refer to [Where to Store Files](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html#where-to-store-files).

For Libraries like Music, Picture or Document, you can follow the below steps to access the folder:

1. Create a custom plugin(`cordova-plugin-capability-manager`) to manage the capabilities on windows platform(below is the plugin.xml):

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"
           id="cordova-plugin-capability-manager" version="0.0.1">
       <name>Capability Manager</name>
       <description>Cordova Capability Manager Plugin</description>
       <license>Apache 2.0</license>
       <keywords>cordova,device</keywords>
       <platform name="windows">
           <config-file target="package.appxmanifest" parent="/Package/Capabilities">
               <uap:Capability Name="documentsLibrary" />
               <uap:Capability Name="picturesLibrary" />
               <uap:Capability Name="musicLibrary" />
           </config-file>
           <config-file target="package.appxmanifest" parent="/Package/Applications/Application/Extensions" >
                   <uap:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
                       <uap:FileTypeAssociation Name="text">
                           <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
                               <uap:FileType>.txt</uap:FileType>
                           </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
                       </uap:FileTypeAssociation>
                   </uap:Extension>
           </config-file>
       </platform>
   </plugin>
   ```

   **Notes:** If you want to use `documentLibrary`, you will need to declare fileTypeAssociation in windows manifest file as shown in the above codes. For details, please refer to documentLibrary's Prerequisites of [KnownFolders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.KnownFolders).
2. Add the plugin manually(Include the plugin folder into your project, add it in `config.xml`). And **please do not add this plugin through VS `config.xml` designer as you will get xml parse error, and plugin won't be added successfully.**:

   ```
   </widget>
        ...
       <plugin name="cordova-plugin-capability-manager" spec="~0.0.1"  />
   </widget>
   ```
3. Use WinRT [KnownFolders API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.KnownFolders) directly in your cordova js file:

   ```
   if (cordova.platformId === "windows")
   {
    Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.documentsLibrary
       .createFileAsync("abc.txt", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting)
       .then(function (file) {
           var abc = file;
       }, function (error) {
           var cba = error;
       });
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for this. You're saying that, in essence, I can use this code to copy the files between Documents and the app folder. Then I can do all my work inside the app folder and use `cordova-plugin-file` and `cordova-sqlite-storage`